# Plotting data with a non-linear format to a linear one

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

We have a list :

```
mainlist={ {1.*10^-6, 0.496422}, {0.000011, 
  0.487914}, {0.000021, 0.483133}, {0.000031, 0.479348}, {0.000041, 
 0.476095}, {0.000051, 0.473187}, {0.000061, 0.470526}, {0.000071, 
 0.468053}, {0.000081, 0.46573},{0.0001, 0.461636}, {0.0002, 0.444089}, 
 {0.0003, 0.429989}, {0.0004,0.417684}, {0.0005, 0.406535}};
```

We have exploited

```
fitting=NonlinearModelFit[mainlist, 0.5 - b g^0.5, {a, b}, g];
```

*Mathematica* gave us `0.5-4.01902*g^0.5`. We can plot `mainlist` and `fitting` in one plot

```
listplot = ListPlot[mainlist, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.005}, All}];
plot=Plot[0.5-4.01909 g^0.5,{g,0,0.005}];
Show[{plot,listplot}]
```

[image]

But, the desired case for us is a linear **show**.

In fact, however we know that the fitting function is described by `g^0.5`, but we wish to have plot with linear form as (we don't understand how we do this job):

[image]

Comment: Maybe use `ListLogPlot` and `LogPlot` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is

$$y=0.5-bx^{1/2},$$

so

$$\log\frac{0.5-y}{b}=\frac{1}{2}\log x.$$

That means you need

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[mainlist, 0.5 - b g^0.5, b, g];
coeff = nlm["ParameterTableEntries"][[1, 1]];

data = {#[[1]], (0.5 - #[[2]])/coeff} & /@ mainlist;
plot1 = ListLogLogPlot[data, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Then

```
plot2 = LogLogPlot[x^0.5, {x, $MachineEpsilon, 0.005}, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But a surprising point: We have 14 pairs in mainlist. In interval [10^-6, 10^-4) we have 9 pairs. And for [10^-4, 5*10^-4] we have just 5 pairs. In the final plot the pairs in the mentioned intervals are not distributed correctly I think.

Comment: For example: in [10^-6, 10^-4) we do not have 9 pairs in the plot!

Comment: Do `Log10@mainlist` and see for yourself; I don't get your objection - that's how your data points are distributed.

Comment: I can understand. You are right. Your answer is correct.

Comment: So sorry: A question: When you told Log(0.5-y)/coeff = 0.5 Log x in the second equation, but in `ListLogLogPlot[data]`, the 0.5 coefficient before Log x will not be considered!!

Comment: Because I think ListLogLogPlot just takes a Log from x and does not assume proposed 0.5 before the originate format!

Comment: The `0.5` is related to the slope in both plots.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html) instead of `NonlinearModelFit`.

```
fit[x_] = Fit[mainlist, {1, x}, x] (*{1,x} as you are fitting a+bx*)
Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 0.0005}, Epilog -> Point[mainlist]]
```

> 0.48385 - 167.767 x

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want a linear plot, you'll need to plot $y$ vs $x$ with $x$ having a square root scale.

```
ListPlot[mainlist, ScalingFunctions -> {{#^0.5 &, #^2 &}, None},
 ImageSize -> Large, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {{0, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}/10000., None}}]
```

[image: Plot of data with x on a square root scale]

However, you might consider a more general curve because a fit with two additional parameters provides a much better fit.

```
fit1 = NonlinearModelFit[mainlist, 0.5 - b g^0.5, {b}, g];
fit2 = NonlinearModelFit[mainlist, a - b g^c, {a, b, c}, g];
```

The residual variance of `fit2` is only 1.2% of `fit1`.  The AIC value for `fit2` is way smaller than for `fit1`.  Theoretically the 0.5 values might be true but your data is saying something different.  The 95% confidence interval for `c` does not include 0.5:

```
fit2["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

[image: Confidence interval table]

Here are the two residual plots:

```
ListPlot[{Transpose[{fit1["PredictedResponse"], fit1["FitResiduals"]}],
  Transpose[{fit2["PredictedResponse"], fit2["FitResiduals"]}]}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Predicted response", 
    "Fit residuals"}, PlotLegends -> {"0.5-b g^0.5", "a-b g^c"}]
```

[image: Residual plots]

However, there's still a strong "pattern" to the residuals of the better fit which suggests there still something else going on:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{fit2["PredictedResponse"], fit2["FitResiduals"]}],
  Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Predicted response", "Fit residuals"}]
```

[image: Residual plot for better fitting model]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your clarified answer. I think it is why my fitting is not more correct than a-b g^c.